# build linq queries dynamically

Tags: linq

suppose I have a string list, like

```
list<string> cols = {"id", "name", "position"}.
```

This list is generated dynamically, and each one in this list represents a column name in a database table.

what I want to do is create a linq query dynamically which returns these columns only.

```
var q = from e in employ
        select new {
          id = id,
          name = name,
          position = position
};
```

How can I generate a query like that based on the input column lists?

Comment: Dynamic Linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx can do this

Answer (score 0):

As Chocoboboy said, `System.Linq.Dynamic` would help. Unfortunately, this is not included in the .NET framework, but you can download it from the Scott Guthrie's blog.
In your case, you need to call `Select(string selector)` (with the column list hard-coded or sourced from a list). Optionally, my example includes a dynamic `Where` clause (`Where("salary >= 50")`):

```
List<string> cols = new List<string>(new [] { "id", "name", "position" });
var employ = new[] { new { id = 1, name = "A", position = "Manager", salary = 100 },
    new { id = 2, name = "B", position = "Dev", salary = 50 },
    new { id = 3, name = "C", position = "Secretary", salary = 25 }
};
string colString = "new (id as id, name as name, position as position)";
//string colString = "new ( " + (from i in cols select i + " as " + i).Aggregate((r, i) => r + ", " + i) + ")";
var q = employ.AsQueryable().Where("salary >= 50").Select(colString);
foreach (dynamic e in q)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", e.id, e.name, e.position));
```

However, this approach somehow defeats the purpose of LINQ strongly-typed queries, so I would use it with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expression Trees to build dynamic Linq queries.
Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx