# C# linq generate query dynamically

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [build linq queries dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006691/build-linq-queries-dynamically)

linq update query dynamically

I have a method passing code id, e.g. if code - 1 then i select data from tbl A and if code - 2 I want to select from tbl B

e.g.  I tried to do: but the code doesnt work

```
 public static void Update(int code, int userid)
 {
   var query =
            (from t1 in code == 1? dataContext.tb1 : dataContext.tb2
             where t1.Id == userid
             select t1).SingleOrDefault();
 }
```

how can I generate query dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that tb1 and tb2 are of different type you can not.

Comment: what do you mean different type of tables?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What errors are you getting?

Comment: the "dataContext.tb1 : dataContext.tb2" is highlighted, error:Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Data.Linq.Table<tb1>' and 'System.Data.Linq.Table<tb2>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious from your question but is sounds like you are using some linq wrapper on database access. If this is the case then it is most likely that you cannot crate query that has condition on source of data. The easiest way to crate such if is to crate two queries as simple as that:

```
public static void Update(int code, int userid)
{
   SomeType result;
   if(code == 1)
   { 
       result =
        (from t1 in dataContext.tb1
         where t1.Id == userid
         select t1).SingleOrDefault();
   }
   else
   {
       result =
        (from t1 in dataContext.tb2
         where t1.Id == userid
         select t1).SingleOrDefault();
   }
  // and do something with result
}
```

**Edit**

On now it obvious that you are using linq to sql so the above stands. But your error is easier then that you have ternary operator that returns two different types on true and false side and that is the error.