# Pass the table and column dynamically in dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I searched a lot, but couldn't find what I was looking exactly. This may be very simple. Normally in LINQ we write the select query like this:

```
var entityModel = new StudentEntities();
var dept = (from a in entityModel.STUDENT where a.NAME != null select a.DEPARTMENT).Distinct().OrderBy(w => w); 
//STUDENT- table, NAME-column name, DEPARTMENT-column name
```

How to write the same query using dynamic LINQ? Here the table name and column name names will be selected from either some winForm controls (textbox/combobox) or string. Tried this:

```
var dept = "(from a in entityModel." + tableName + "where a." + cbo1.Text.ToString + "!= null select a."+cbo2.Text.ToString +").Distinct().OrderBy(w => w)";
```

This is not working. Can anyone point me to the right direction, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13796998/11683

Comment: Selecting from different tables will yield different result types. However it's possible using dynamic variables and chaining query using ifs - whose cases are selected by your comboboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You need to generate your dynamic SQL and run it over your database.

There's [this library: Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), but it isn't as dynamic as you want.